# Canvas clipPath only works on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to use canvas.clipPath() to draw a bitmap image inside a constraining circle similar to to Clipping activity in the APP demos. The problem is that my code only renders properly on the emulator, when run on an actual Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.2 it appears as if the clipPath works more like a rectangular clipping. I'm totally stumped! I create a new Path() and decode a bitmap in my view ctor. Any suggestions?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Point point = getPoint();
    path.reset();
    canvas.clipPath(path); // makes the clip empty
    path.addCircle(point.x, point.y, getScale() * 140, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.REPLACE);

    Point scaledSize = new Point((int) (bitmapSize.x * getScale()), (int) (bitmapSize.y * getScale()));
    Point topLeft = new Point((point.x - (scaledSize.x / 2)), (point.y - (scaledSize.y / 2)));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new Rect(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, topLeft.x + scaledSize.x, topLeft.y + scaledSize.y), paint);
}
```

**Galaxy Nexus**
[image: GalaxyNexus]

**Emulator**

[image: Emulator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clipPath is not supported for hardware acceleration. 
You can create a clipped bitmap using something like this:

```
Bitmap clippedBitmap = ... // Create same size bitmap as source
Paint paint = new Paint();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(clippedBitmap);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(PAint.Style.FILL);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));    
canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Do this once, and then draw the clipped bitmap instead of the source one

Comment: Perfect! That works like a charm! Now what if I want to animate the clipping, decrease/increase the size of my circle? Would I need to create new bitmaps for each clipping or could I reuse the bitmap and it's associated canvas, redrawing from the original source each time?

Comment: You can use one bitmap, draw a smaller or larger inner circle and then copy the masked area from the source bitmap into the new bitmap. The clipped bitmap will have a smaller or larger transparent area depending on the animation stage.

Answer (score 4):

ClipPath is not supported for hardware acceleration

You can close hardware acceleration use this:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: Starting from which API does it work well? I've noticed it's ok not to use it on Android 4.4, for example.

Answer (score 2):

ClipPath is not supported for hardware acceleration. Check the link below under the topic Unsupported Drawing Operations.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#drawing-support

You can use the below for reference and modify the paramters of draw circle to suit your needs.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawingView dv = new DrawingView(this);
    dv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    setContentView(dv);
}

class DrawingView extends View{
Bitmap bitmap;


 public DrawingView(Context context)
 {
 super(context);
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sqaure);   
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 //paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 // paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
 canvas.drawBitmap(getclip(), 0, 0, paint);//originally x and y is o and o .

 } 
 public Bitmap getclip()
 {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight());
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
//paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2-40,
        bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2-40, paint);
    // change the parameters accordin to your needs.
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
return output;
    }
  } 
}
```

[image]